# Ignore variable dependency of node_module webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, babeljs, webpack-5

I have built a library that I want to use in a Next.JS project. Within this library a certain dependency is using an import via a string passed into a require statement within the source code where the import is taking place. This is causing webpack to not recognize the import. I don't want to change code within any node_modules as this is not a preferred approach but how can I ensure that my project using the library I built is able to compile and run?

Within file_using_string_passed_into_require_to_get_import.js:

```
let importName = "./potential_import_A.js"
if(condition){
importName = "./potential_import_B.js"
}
module.exports = require(importName)
```

This is the folder structure:

```
Project/
    | node_modules
      | my-library
        | node_modules
          | library-dependency
             | file_using_string_passed_into_require_to_get_import.js
             | potential_import_A.js
             | potential_import_B.js
```

Comment: `causing webpack to not recognize the import` what is the error there? And can you include the file which you use `file_using_string_passed_into_require_to_get_import` also in your tree?

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './potential_import_A' @smilyface

Comment: @smilyface https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-utils/blob/master/src/fetch.js this is the exact file I am referring to when I mention `file_using_string_passed_into_require_to_get_import`

Answer (score 0):

**To create a local (unpublished) library package**

- Create a 'my-library' folder (outside your current project dir).
- Do `npm init` (Folder must include the 'package.json' )
- Include source code (potential_import_A), exporting any desired functions.

**In the actual project folder:**

- `cd` into the folder of the project that needs to *use* your library.
- Run `npm install --save  local/path/to/my-library`.
- The `--save` will add the package to your dependencies in the project's package.json file, as it does with 3rd party published packages.  It will also add a copy of the source code to the node modules folder of the project, as always.

**Importing your new library:**

- import/require the package as you would normally, from any project. 
  For example
  `import { myFunction } from "my-library"`

Comment: So within the my-library include the source code of the dependency within the bundle?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should not be written/copied manually to the node_modules.

Comment: @SreeGrandhe , Is this helped? Let me know if any other problems you face

Comment: https://github.com/Three0Dev/JS-SDK - This is my library https://github.com/Three0Dev/Tweeter - this is my Next.Js/Webpack project

Comment: This is not working because even if I bundle it in with my own library it doesn't know how to resolve the file

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by excluding node_modules from the webpack build. Since I am using Next.JS this is within my next.config.js

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (
    config,
    {
      buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack,
    },
  ) => {
    if (isServer) {
      config.target = 'node';

      config.node = {
        __dirname: true,
        global: true,
        __filename: true,
      };

      config.externals = [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
      config.externalsPresets = {
        node: true, // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
};
```